# ServiceHostFactory with multiple bindings

Tags: c#, wcf

How do I use a ServiceHostFactory with multiple bindings?

This is what I've tried and I keep getting issues, one after another error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace WcfService7
{
    public class clsMyOwnServiceHost : ServiceHostFactory
    {    
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type t, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            BasicHttpBinding basicbinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
            WSHttpBinding wsbinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(t, baseAddresses);

            foreach(Uri uri in baseAddresses)
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), basicbinding, uri);
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), wsbinding, uri);       
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, uri);          
            }

            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uri needs to be different for each binding type.

> TCP:
>   net.tcp://{hostname}[:port]/{location}
>   Basic HTTP:
>   http://{hostname}[:port]/{location}
>   WS HTTP:
>   http://{hostname}:{port}/{location}

Comment: thats right...but...what should it be? How should I change it?

Comment: @Josh, actually you are doing something else wrong here: for URI you just need to pass a relative address - not the base address.

Comment: Assuming Uri[] baseAddresses are specified correctly (as in my answer, but without the {location}) then all you need is the {location} string.