# Multiple contracts with same bindings..How?

Tags: c#, wcf

How do I use multiple contracts with the same binding on the same port through C# code?

Would appreciate any simple code snipplet...

Thanks so much

Comment: Duplicate of [ServiceHostFactory with multiple bindings??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970630/servicehostfactory-with-multiple-bindings) asked just two minutes earlier!

Comment: No that one is through servicehostfactory to host in IIS and this one is for a windows Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
public class Service : IServiceContract1, IServiceContract2
{
  ...
}
```

Configuration (can be easily rewritten to code if you add Endpoint instances to ServiceHost by calling AddServiceEndpoint)

```
<services>
  <service name="Service">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="first" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IServiceContract1" />
    <endpoint address="second" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IServiceContract2" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: what would be the base address if I need to include a TCP endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no "simple code snippet" for this. Use the following article to get started and just add more `ServiceHost` objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

If you haven't already, it would be wise to get a book on WCF.